# Any other ways I can stop the <front> page from being cached by boost?

Tags: 7, caching

My drupal 7 site has Boost module (7.1.beta1, the version previous to the current release) installed and I didn't change any settings from the stock install. I saved the settings configuration with the `<front>` exception, generated the htaccess code, added it to my root htaccess file, turned Drupal core cache for anonymous users off... Everything works, ie, pages get cached to the boost cache directory and anonymous browsing is served from the boost cache. Only problem is that the front page is being cached even when my boost setting exception using the default `<front>` should be preventing the front page from being cached. I apologize if this is a redundant thread,I searched but mostly people have the opposite problem (ie, they want the front page cached-whereas I don't). I've also cleared the cache via /performance tab after enabling it and made sure there wasn't a boost cache for the front page .

Does anyone know why the boost exception setting isn't working for the front page? Is there perhaps another way to hack boost for this one page to not be 'boosted'? Thanks.

Comment: How does your exception look? Do you use <front>?

Comment: Yeah its the only thing in the exceptions text area.

Comment: The only thing i can imagine from my experience is that maybe there's still the frontpage-html files in the boost-cache folder. Other than that, i have no more suggestions...

Comment: Yeah, I cleared that boost cache folder and it just keeps regenerating back. Thanks for your suggestions, appreciate your help.

Comment: Just a note, but as the front page is most often hit, it's usually the one you want to ensure is cached / served rapidly.

Comment: Ordinarily we would want the front page cached, but we want content and feeds fresh as soon as possible on the front page, and almost all other pages don't get new content so we make the lifetime high.  We're having performance issues and although the homepage does take the most resources, and with no way to set multiple different Max cache lifetimes for different pages, we decided to not cache the front page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the actual url of your front page?
If your frontpage is the default ( /node ) then you need to add both 'node' and '' to your exceptions list.
Boost treats them differently and keeps a copy of each page in the cache.

You can inspect the cache files that boost creates (these are actually plain html files) in the cache apache root folder.

Comment: Thank you, Mike! The site's url is www.example.com, which is why i thought the default front exception would do it. After looking at site-information it appears that it wasn't that simple.. the url turned out to be www.example.com/3columns#. So I went back to boost, left the front default and added "3columns" to the list and sure enough, it doesn't get cached. Much Appreciated!

Comment: I appreciate that information as well! thx...